# C OpenMP : libgomp: Thread creation failed: Resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

I was trying to do a p basic project and It seems like I have run out of threads? Do you guys know how do can I fix the problem?

Here is the code:

```
int main()
{
    omp_set_num_threads(2150);
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        printf("%d\n",omp_get_thread_num());
    }


    return 0;
}
```

and here is the global compiler setting I have written on "other compiler options" on CodeBlocks:

```
-fopenmp
```

I am getting the error of:

> libgomp: Thread creation failed: Resource temporarily unavailable

I have seen similar threads on the site, but I have not got the answer or solution as of yet.

Specs:

> Intel i5 6400
>
> 2x8GB ram
>
> Windows 10 64 bit

Comment: Well, you set the number of threads to a perversely large number which certainly doesn't reflect any hardware capability, and things broke, Are you really surprised? See things like https://superuser.com/questions/1469924/maximum-threads-limit-per-process-in-windows-10 for a discussion on this area.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is

```
omp_set_num_threads(2150);
```

The OS will impose a limit on the number of threads a process can create. This may be indirect for example by limiting the stack size. Creating 2150 exceeds the limits.

You mention that you've got the intel 15 6400 which is a quad core chip.  Try setting the number of threads to something more reasonable. In your case:

```
omp_set_num_threads(4);
```

For numerical processing, performance will likely suffer when using more than 4 threads on a 4 core system