# Failed thread creation when parallelizing a branching recursive subroutine in Fortran with OpenMP

Tags: performance, recursion, parallel-processing, fortran, openmp

I am writing a recursive subroutine in Fortran that expands as a binary tree (i.e. the procedure calls itself twice until it reaches the end of a branch). The general algorithmic logic is:

'''

```
call my_subroutine(inputs, output)
  use input to generate possible new_input(:,1) and new_input(:,2)
  do i=1,2
    call my_subroutine(new_input(:,i), new_output(i))
  enddo
  output = best(new_output(1), new_output(2))
```

'''

In principle, this could be substantially accelerated through parallel computing, however when I use OpenMP to parallelize the loop, running the resulting executable aborts with the error:

*libgomp: Thread creation failed: Resource temporarily unavailable Thread creation failed: Resource temporarily unavailable*

I'm guessing that the stack size is too large, but I haven't found a resolution or workaround. Are there ways I can use parallel computing to improve the performance of this kind of algorithm?

-Does OpenMP or gfortran have options to help avoid these issues?

-Would it help to parallelize only above or below a certain level in the tree?

-Would c or c++ be a better option for this application?

I am working on macOS Catalina. Stack size is hard capped at 65532.
My environment variables are:

*OMP_NESTED=True*

*OMP_DYNAMIC=True*

Comment: Please show a full code - the devil is in the detail. Tasks would be the normal way in OMP to do this. but without a minimal example it is very difficult to help.

Comment: BTW I suspect what you are seeing is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61983425/c-openmp-libgomp-thread-creation-failed-resource-temporarily-unavailable and a result of nested parallelism rather than tasks - but without code I can't tell.

Comment: I'm unsure if I can display the exact code as it is a prototype for my job, but I may be able  to create an equivalent example to demo. I came across the thread you mentioned, though unfortunately limiting the maximum number of threads with omp_set_num_threads did not resolve the issue.
Thank you for the suggestion to use 'tasks' rather than nested parallelism. I hadn't considered this as I didn't have a solid understanding of the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sounds more like your code is creating too many threads due to a very deep recursion. There are ways to mitigate it. For example, OpenMP 4.5 introduced the concept of maximum active levels controlled by the [*max-active-levels-var* ICV](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.1/openmpsu31.html#x49-480002.4.1) (internal control variable). You may set its value by either setting the `OMP_MAX_ACTIVE_LEVELS` environment variable or by calling `omp_set_max_active_levels()`. Once the level of nesting reaches that specified by *max-active-levels-var*, parallel regions nested further deeper are deactivated, i.e., they will execute sequentially without spawning new threads.

If your compiler does not support OpenMP 4.5, or if you want your code to be backward compatible with older compilers, then you can do it manually by tracking the level of nesting and deactivating the parallel region. For the latter, there is the `if(b)` clause that when applied to the parallel region makes it active only when `b` evaluates to `.true.`. A sample parallel implementation of your code:

```
subroute my_subroutine(inputs, output, level)
  use input to generate possible new_input(:,1) and new_input(:,2)
!$omp parallel do schedule(static,1) if(level<max_levels)
  do i=1,2
    call my_subroutine(new_input(:,i), new_output(i), level+1)
  enddo
!$omp end parallel do
  output = best(new_output(1), new_output(2))
end subroutine my_subroutine
```

The top level call to `my_subroutine` has to be with a `level` equal to `0`.

No matter how exactly you implement it, you'll need to experiment with the value of the maximum level. The optimal value will depend on the number of CPUs/cores and the arithmetic intensity of the code and will vary from system to system.

A better alternative to the `parallel do` construct would be to use OpenMP tasks, again, with a cut-off at a certain level of nesting. The good thing about tasks is that you can fix the number of OpenMP threads in advance and the tasking runtime will take care of workload distribution.

```
subroutine my_subroutine(inputs, output, level)
  use input to generate possible new_input(:,1) and new_input(:,2)
!$omp taskloop shared(new_input, new_output) final(level>=max_levels)
  do i=1,2
    call my_subroutine(new_input(:,i), new_output(i), level+1)
  end do
!$omp taskwait
  output = best(new_output(1), new_output(2))
end subroutine my_subroutine
```

Here, each iteration the loop becomes a separate task. If `max_levels` of nesting has been reached, the tasks become final, which means they will not be deferred (i.e., will execute sequentially) and each nested task will be final too, effectively stopping parallel execution further down the recursion tree. Task loops are a convenience feature introduced in OpenMP 4.5. With earlier compilers, the following equivalent code will do:

```
subroutine my_subroutine(inputs, output, level)
  use input to generate possible new_input(:,1) and new_input(:,2)
  do i=1,2
!$omp task shared(new_input, new_output) final(level>=max_levels)
    call my_subroutine(new_input(:,i), new_output(i), level+1)
!$omp end task
  end do
!$omp taskwait
  output = best(new_output(1), new_output(2))
end subroutine my_subroutine
```

There are no `parallel` constructs in the tasking code. Instead, you need to call `my_subroutine` from within a parallel region and the idiomatic way is to do it like this:

```
!$omp parallel
!$omp single
  call my_subroutine(inputs, output, 0)
!$omp end single
!$omp end parallel
```

There is a fundamental difference between the nested parallel version and the one using tasks. In the former case, at each recursive level the current thread forks in two and each thread does one half of the computation in parallel. Limiting the level of active parallelism is needed here in order to prevent the runtime from spawning too many threads and exhausting the system resources. In the latter case, at each recursive level two new tasks are created and deferred for later, possibly parallel execution by the team of threads associated with the parallel region. The number of threads stays the same and the cut-off here limits the build-up of tasking overhead, which is way smaller than the overhead of spawning new parallel regions. Hence, the optimal value of `max_levels` for the tasking code will differ significantly from the optimal value for the nested parallel code.

Comment: Thank you Hristo! I had tried the second approach with limited success. The program seems to get stuck at certain points (possibly waiting for different parallel regions to synchronize.) I must have been looking at old documentation as I didn't see the '''OMP_MAX_LEVELS"' variable. As Ian suggested, the 'parallel do' directive might not be appropriate for this application.

Comment: That's understandable. `OMP_MAX_ACTIVE_LEVELS` first appeared in OpenMP 4.5. The specification itself was released in November 2015 and compilers with full support for it came out a while after.

Comment: There is nothing intrinsic wrong with `parallel do`, as long as both recursive subcalls take more or less the same amount of time. Of course, there are better solutions. For example - OpenMP tasks. But having a cut-off for parallelism at a certain level of recursion applies there too.

Comment: This may be an issue in my particular implementation as some branches are likely to finish much faster than others. Mathematically, each level of the tree are independent of one another and could hypothetically be handled by separate processors but the advantage goes away if they spend most of their time waiting for cousin branches to resolve.

Comment: In that case, OpenMP tasks are a better alternative. I'll update the answer accordingly.

Comment: Good to know. I have done some tests using OMP tasks, and though this is much more robust, I haven't had consistent performance gains. I'll have to experiment quite a bit more to figure out if I am poorly utilizing OMP or if the structure of my code is not well suited for multi-threading. If I make any breakthroughs or useful discoveries I'll update this thread. *no pun intended